# Software to draw Binary Search Tree or any other tree structures

Tags: draw, binary-search-tree

I need to plot BSTs on the computer.

Is there any software that does this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this look like what you are looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334773/Graphical-BinaryTrees

Comment: wow!this is what actually i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

well..I just found one and it seems to do the job quite well.

[TreeForm Syntax Tree Drawing Software](https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeform/)